# it is possible to insert one to many relationship to database together?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

according to picture picture below we have and ERD model
[image]

I want to whole of data insert to database at the same time,
but my problem is how can insert a one to many relationships
that have another relationship with itself

I think I must run a query to make an entry and after that insert to it another relation data that has it.

my means was it isn't possible to insert data that have a relation ship together and we must insert it step by step and up to down

are you agree?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTSOS.png)

Comment: In which table in your diagram are you trying to insert the data in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL you can't get the auto-increment values when you do a multi row insert.

It's fne to insert the rows one by one, get the auto-increment value and then insert the secondary rows via multi-row inserts.

The performance penalty for doing it with multiple queries is not that bad if you do it in a single transaction.

Comment: I think so,we must first insert top table and after that insert secondary query,and it's looks like just a solution.